# Counting grouped and concatinated results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make database that contains products in storage. Every product contains unknown amount of possible "selections" that defines what version of product is in storage.

For example product `Sofa` that contains selections `Color: Black`, `Legs: Wood` and `Material: Leather` while product `Bed` contains only selection `Mattress: Hard`.

I've used GROUP_CONCAT to get all sofas that are same kind like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product, p.size, p.color,p.storage,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.selection, ': ' ,s.option) AS selection
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN selection s
       ON p.id = s.product_id
WHERE product.id = 123
GROUP BY s.id;
```

The question is how do I count how many products was concatenated in query or is it even possible to count with single query?

EDIT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_storage.product, product_storage.size,
product_storage.color, product_storage.storage,
GROUP_CONCAT(product_storage_selection.selection, 
product_storage_selection.option) as selection
FROM product_storage_link
INNER JOIN product_storage 
ON product_storage_link.product_storage_id = product_storage.id
INNER JOIN product_storage_selection 
ON product_storage.id = product_storage_selection.product_storage_id
WHERE product_storage_link.product_id = 7207
GROUP BY product_storage.id;
```

Gives

```
Product    Color    Size    Selection
Product1   Black    10x10   Selection1:Option1, Selection2:Option1
Product1   Black    10x10   Selection1:Option2, Selection2:Option1
Product1   White    10x10   Selection1:Option1, Selection2:Option1
```

I try to get count of duplicates in these two tables and got same selections from other table. Hope this clears the question.

So the goal is to get for example:

```
Product    Color    Size    Selection                                amount
Product1   Black    10x10   Selection1:Option1, Selection2:Option1   3
Product1   Black    10x10   Selection1:Option2, Selection2:Option1   1
Product1   White    10x10   Selection1:Option1, Selection2:Option1   2
```

The part from database:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fec0b

EDIT 2:

This is the whole table with data.

```
| id | product |  size |    color | storage |        selection |         option |
|----|---------|-------|----------|---------|------------------|----------------|
|  1 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  1 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  2 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  2 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  3 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  3 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  4 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  4 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  5 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  5 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  6 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  6 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  7 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  7 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
```

First product constructs from these values.

```
| id | product |  size |    color | storage |        selection |         option |
|----|---------|-------|----------|---------|------------------|----------------|
|  1 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  1 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |

|  2 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  2 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |

|  3 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  3 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
```

And should come out as:

```
| product |  size |    color | storage |                                                   selection |         amount |
|---------|-------|----------|---------|-------------------------------------------------------------|----------------|
|     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1:Vaihtoehto 1,Lisävaihtoehto 2:Vaihtoehto 1 |              3 |
```

Second product constructs from these:

```
| id | product |  size |    color | storage |        selection |         option |
|----|---------|-------|----------|---------|------------------|----------------|
|  4 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  4 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  5 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 2 |
|  5 |     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 2 |
```

And come out as:

```
| product |  size |    color | storage |                                                     selection |         amount |
|---------|-------|----------|---------|---------------------------------------------------------------|----------------|
|     asd | Koko1 |    Väri1 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1:Vaihtoehto2, Lisävaihtoehto 2,2 Vaihtoehto 2 |              2 |
```

Third come from these:

```
| id | product |  size |    color | storage |        selection |         option |
|----|---------|-------|----------|---------|------------------|----------------|
|  6 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  6 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  7 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1 |   Vaihtoehto 1 |
|  7 |     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 2 | 2 Vaihtoehto 1 |
```

And should produce:

```
| product |  size |    color | storage |                                                       selection |         amount |
|---------|-------|----------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|----------------|
|     asd | Koko2 | 2 Väri 2 |   false | Lisävaihtoehto 1:Vaihtoehto 1, Lisävaihtoehto 2:2 Vaihtoehto 1  |              2 |
```

Hope this helps. This is kind of hard to explain.

Comment: add a `count(s.option)` or `count(distinct s.selection)` (or whatever you want to count)

Comment: @Solarflare Tried that. It returns only amount of selections in product, not count of products in storage that contains these selections.

Comment: You asked for `count how many products was concatenated`. What do you want to get instead? The sum of storage? Then use `sum(storage)` (assuming storage is your stock-value). It would be easier if you would add some sample data and the desired output (then we don't have to guess what you mean or what your data looks like).

Comment: It is still not clear to me what e.g. "amount=3" means. You have to provide the sample data that leads to this 3, 1 and 2. It will probably really just be a matter of choosing the correct column to count.

Comment: Edited sqlfiddle to the answer. Contains some test rows.

Comment: Assuming this fiddle should belong to your example result data: it still doesn't explain what "amount=3" means. In your example data, you have 14 rows in your `product_storage_selection`-table. Please describe how that data should give the amounts "3,1,2".

Comment: In latest example should produce three rows with values 3, 2, 2. Should've use the real table examples from the beginning to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please don't write: "something like this", I still have to guess then what you mean. Please add all 14 rows to your question and describe which row should count to which result row. You can e.g. order them in a way that the rows that belong to the "3" stand together (it doesn't have to be just 3 rows, distinct and such can take care of stuff like that), but you have to identify the rows that go into the number "3". If there is some other logic (e.g. rows count several times), describe that too. And/or describe: What do you do by hand if you have these 14 rows to get to the numbers 3,2,2.

Comment: Ok, the reason your query doesn't give you the result you want is that is has basically nothing to do with what you finally described - that is why we couldn't find your value in there. You can use the following code: `select product, size, color, storage, selection, count(id)
from (
SELECT product_storage.id, product_storage.product, ... the rest of your code ...  = 7207
GROUP BY product_storage.id) as sublist group by selection, product, size, color, storage;` to get your result. Unfortunately your datamodel is "strange", that's why it gets a little complicated.

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product, p.size, p.color,p.storage,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.selection, ': ' ,s.option) AS selection,
COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN selection s
       ON p.id = s.product_id
WHERE product.id = 123
GROUP BY s.id;
```

---

```
tableTest
+-----------------------------------------------+
| ID | name        | country   | home_city      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1 | AAA          | UK        | Cambridge      |
| 2 | BBB          | Canada    | Toronto        |
| 3 | CCC          | UK        | Leeds          |
| 4 | DDD          | USA       | Newyork        |
+-----------------------------------------------+


SELECT country,count(*) as countryCount
FROM tableTest
GROUP BY country

+-----------------------+
|country  |countryCount |
+-----------------------+
|UK       |  2          |
|Canada   |  1          |
|USA      |  1          |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Tried. Returns amount of selections in product, not products with selections in storage.

Comment: Could you provide the tables and desired output.Create the schema in sqlfiddle and post the link with your question .  @Jester